# Avro Enum Serialization

Tags: java, avro

How To serialize java enum in avro .

Example I have enum-

```
enum color {

WHITE,RED,GREEN

}
```

avro schema

```
{ 
  "type": "enum",
  "name": "Color",
  "symbols" : ["WHITE", "RED", "GREEN"]
}
```

which interface should enum implement for avro serialization

Answer (score 2):

To Serialize enum in avro it should implement GenericEnumSymbol interface

NOTE:  Schema field name should be SCHEMA$ because avro API class SpecifiedData use reflection to get this field getDeclaredField("SCHEMA$").

Comment: Hello @shivam Could you please elaborate on your answer? When I do `public enum ColorEnum implements GenericEnumSymbol` I get the error `Comparable cannot be inherited with different type arguments`.